# Is there a way to perform .filter and .find at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dealing with templates and finding certain elements for future updating when responding to events. However, I'd like the ability to mark these elements with a class, data-* attribute, or something else without having to know the markup beforehand.

Is there a way to perform a [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and a [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) search at the same time?

Comment: @undefined Like `elements.filter(selector).end().find(selector)`?

Comment: If you want to store the new collection, no, `.end()` doesn't help here. However, you can wrap the elements with another element and then use `.find()` method.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to use an [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) operation to combine the two results, but this seems a bit convoluted.

```
elements.filter(selector).add(elements.find(selector))
```

Comment: Are the `elements` siblings?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas For my purposes, yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

Simple extension for this purpose:

```
jQuery.fn.findIn = function(selector){
  return this.filter(selector).add(this.find(selector));
}
```

Then simply call `.findIn('.your-selector')`.

*currently taking suggestions for a better name.*